# React formik multiple select issue on Reinitialize data value on empty

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

I am using react formik and react-select, In the form  I have issue when click  load data button the values are not bind in the select field they are set as empty Please help us.

codesandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-paper-3eqxp?file=/src/RegisterForm.js:707-719

Thank for Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to my fork based on your example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-austin-elj6q?file=/src/RegisterForm.js

A small trick here, you have to resetForm if you want to click load button a second time.